# Invalid column name Bintype, binnumber, bintypedesc

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot-table

I am using temp table to create a dynamic pivot table But I am receiving the error message.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 76 Invalid column name 'binnumber'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 76 Invalid column name 'bintype'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 92 Invalid column name 'binnumber'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 92 Invalid column name 'bintypedesc'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 92 Invalid column name 'bintype'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    left(a.[PartNumber], 3) + '-' + substring(a.partnumber, 4, 10) AS Partnumber,
    d.statusname,
    [SoldQuantity],
    [AverageDailySale],
    [NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
    (substring(e.Binnumber, 3, 1)) AS LEVEL,
    e.QtyInStock,
    f.[BinType],
    (CASE WHEN f.BinType = 0 THEN 'unknown' WHEN f.bintype = 11 THEN 'fullpallet' WHEN f.BinType = 15 THEN 'halfpallet' WHEN f.BinType = 21 THEN 'cartonsmall' WHEN f.bintype = 23 THEN 'cartonmedium' WHEN f.bintype = 25 THEN 'cartonlarge' WHEN f.bintype = 27 THEN 'cartoncooler' WHEN f.bintype = 31 THEN 'eaches' WHEN f.BinType = 51 THEN 'totepick1cell' WHEN f.bintype = 52 THEN 'totepick2cell' WHEN f.bintype = 53 THEN 'totepick3cell' WHEN f.bintype = 54 THEN 'totepick4cell' WHEN f.bintype = 58 THEN 'totepick8cell' WHEN f.bintype = 66 THEN 'Totepick16cell' WHEN f.bintype = 71 THEN 'cage' WHEN f.bintype = 73 THEN 'cart' WHEN f.bintype = 75 THEN 'tote' WHEN f.BinType = 77 THEN 'pallet' WHEN f.bintype = 91 THEN 'dropoff' WHEN f.bintype = 93 THEN 'staging' ELSE NULL END) AS BintypeDesc,
    f.[MinQuantity],
    f.[MaxQuantity]
INTO #temp
FROM [Inventory].[inventory].[TBL_30DaySales](NOLOCK) AS a
INNER JOIN [Purchasing].[catalog].[TBL_Products](NOLOCK) AS b ON a.partnumber = b.[PartNumber]
INNER JOIN [Finance].[dbo].[Enum.Product.Status](NOLOCK) AS d ON b.STATUS = d.STATUS
INNER JOIN [Finance].[dbo].[Enum.BastianReplenishType](NOLOCK) AS c ON a.[BastianReplenishType] = c.bastianreplenishtype
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [PartNumber],
        [BinType],
        [MinQuantity],
        [MaxQuantity]
    FROM [Inventory].[inventory].[TBL_PartNumberMinMax](NOLOCK) AS B
    WHERE bintype IN ('54', '31')
    ) AS f ON a.PartNumber = f.PartNumber
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Type],
        [Description]
    FROM [Inventory].[inventory].[TBL_BinLocations](NOLOCK) AS C
    ) AS g ON f.BinType = g.Type
    AND a.PartNumber = f.PartNumber
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        partnumber,
        a.binnumber,
        sum(QuantityInStock) AS QtyInStock,
        sum(QuantityCommited) AS QtyCommitted
    FROM [Inventory].[inventory].[VIW_ProductStockBin] AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [Inventory].[inventory].[TBL_BinLocations] AS B WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[BinLocationID] = b.[BinLocationID]
        AND bintype IN ('54', '31')
    GROUP BY partnumber,
        a.binnumber
    ) AS e ON a.PartNumber = e.[PartNumber]
WHERE e.BinNumber NOT IN ('Web00', 'REC10', 'Goback')
    AND substring(e.Binnumber, 3, 1) IN ('a', 'b', 'c');

WITH PM
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        partnumber,
        [SoldQuantity],
        statusname,
        [MaxQuantity],
        [AverageDailySale],
        bintype,
        QtyInStock,
        [A],
        [B],
        [C]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            partnumber,
            statusname,
            LEVEL,
            binnumber,
            [MaxQuantity],
            [AverageDailySale],
            [SoldQuantity],
            QtyInStock,
            bintype
        FROM #temp
        ) AS up
    pivot(count(binnumber) FOR LEVEL IN ([A], [B], [C])) AS PivotTable
    WHERE bintype = '31'
),
PP AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        partnumber,
        [SoldQuantity],
        statusname,
        [AverageDailySale],
        [NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
        QtyInStock,
        bintype,
        (isnull([totepick4cell], 0)) AS totepick4cell
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            partnumber,
            statusname,
            LEVEL,
            binnumber,
            bintypedesc,
            [MaxQuantity],
            [AverageDailySale],
            [SoldQuantity],
            [NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
            bintype,
            QtyInStock
        FROM #temp
        ) AS ut
    pivot(avg([MaxQuantity]) FOR bintypedesc IN ([totepick4cell])) AS PivotTable
    WHERE bintype IN ('54')
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PM.Partnumber,
    PM.SoldQuantity,
    PM.statusname,
    PM.[MaxQuantity],
    PM.[AverageDailySale],
    PM.[A],
    PM.[B],
    PM.[C],
    PP.[NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
    PP.[totepick4cell],
    PM.QtyInStock
FROM PM,
    PP
WHERE PM.partnumber = PP.Partnumber
```

Comment: There really isn't anything anyone here can tell you that isn't already in the error message.   What is your question?    Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Answer (score 0):

In your common table expressions, place your `WHERE` clause above the `PIVOT` inside the `SELECT` with your `#temp` table:

```
WITH PM
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        partnumber,
        [SoldQuantity],
        statusname,
        [MaxQuantity],
        [AverageDailySale],
        bintype,
        QtyInStock,
        [A],
        [B],
        [C]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            partnumber,
            statusname,
            LEVEL,
            binnumber,
            [MaxQuantity],
            [AverageDailySale],
            [SoldQuantity],
            QtyInStock,
            bintype
        FROM #temp
        WHERE bintype = '31'
    ) AS up
    pivot(count(binnumber) FOR LEVEL IN ([A], [B], [C])) AS PivotTable
),
PP AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        partnumber,
        [SoldQuantity],
        statusname,
        [AverageDailySale],
        [NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
        QtyInStock,
        bintype,
        (isnull([totepick4cell], 0)) AS totepick4cell
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            partnumber,
            statusname,
            LEVEL,
            binnumber,
            bintypedesc,
            [MaxQuantity],
            [AverageDailySale],
            [SoldQuantity],
            [NumberOfAislesWithQtyAvailable],
            bintype,
            QtyInStock
        FROM #temp
        WHERE bintype IN ('54')
        ) AS ut
    pivot(avg([MaxQuantity]) FOR bintypedesc IN ([totepick4cell])) AS PivotTable
)
```